# How to store sort function and get it from db

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have component in my angular app with table which gets column's definition with data from server. In db column's definitions store in jsonb. Class in angular app have next definition:

```
export class Table {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  columnsDefinition: ColumnDefinition[];
}

export class ColumnDefinition {
  key: string;
  title: string;
  sortOrder: NzTableSortOrder | null;
  sortFn: NzTableSortFn | null;  // store function for sorting column
  sortFnString: string;  // this is function in string that i get from db
}
```

Which function should i use for cast string to NzTableSortOrder type?
I tryed (just draft)

```
tables.pipe(
  map(tables => { 
    tables.map(t => { 
      t.columnsDefinition.map(definition => { 
        definition.sortOrder = JSON.parse(definition.sortFnString) 
      }) 
    }) 
}))
```

But have an exception "Unexpected token ( in JSON"
In examples of library type NzTableSortFn has next definition:

```
sortFn: (a: DataItem, b: DataItem) => a.name.localCompare(b.name) // for sort by name
```

Or maybe i can store functions in json at once without casting it from string

Comment: JSON doesn’t actually support functions I’m afraid..?

Comment: What is the content of definition.sortFnString returned from API trace value in it before parse then type it here to double check that it is valid json format

Answer (score 0):

Storing functions in db can be dangerous and there are some restrictions. However you can do it. For example you can store compare function as string `"(a, b) => a > b"` and convert string to function using eval: `eval("(a, b) => a > b")`